# Hover or click on one div to affect another

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I'd like to have ability to hover on one div to affect another.

```
<div id="a">1</div>
<div id="b" style="display:none;">2</div>
```

How to hover #a and make #b appear?
I'd like a css3 solution but jquery also is good.

Comment: You want to toggle visibility? And CSS can only select elements further down the DOM tree. Later-siblings, and descendants. It can't work both ways. So JavaScript is required, if you want it to be bidirectional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#a").on({
     mouseenter: function() {
         $("#b").show();
     },
     mouseleave: function() {
         $("#b").hide();
     },
     click: function() {
         alert('Holy crap! Someone clicked me!');
     }
});
```

If you place #b inside #a, you could do it with CSS, otherwise the jQuery solution above should work (with jQuery 1.7+).

Comment: and can you write a func for click event?

Comment: Yupp! Added a click function!

Answer (score 2):

This works in chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/uQfKw/

HTML:

```
<div id="a">1</div>
<div id="b">2</div>
```

CSS:

```
#a + #b {
    display: none;

}
#a:hover + #b {
    display: block;

}
```

Comment: wow! great! i just have to wait, while whole planet chooses chrome)

Comment: [Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) are part of CSS2, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

A css solution would need them to be like this:

```
<div id="a">1
    <div id="b">2</div>
</div>
```

the css to show the block would be:

```
#a:hover #b{
    display: block;
}
```

You can see both of the examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/L93x7/

Comment: If you replace `hover` in my func to `toggle` you will get the appearance/disappearance effect on a click.

Comment: ok. and what if i have 3 diferrent div's which are connected to other 3? I mean: hover div #a > show div #aa. hover #b >show #bb. Hover #c> show #cc. Is there an easy way to do it with js?

Comment: @skip405: You can actually always show the next adjacent sibling without having to do this. You can do it just like he wants, check my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cdYNT/

Comment: The small func I wrote may be further developed and shortened if you use the `.on()` method as well-suggested in another comment. The function would probably use `.toggleClass()`. Consider having a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/7vdgx/